# Sublime Text 2, view syntax definitions within a file

Tags: debugging, syntax, sublimetext2, highlighting

I work at a company that combines xml/html files with python, javascript, and css. I've started working on a syntax highlighter that will include all of these languages (and by 'working on' i mean took xml syntax highlighting, added a few rules and 'include'd the other langues straight in). It works great, but i wanted to make the areas where the language changes a bit more noticeable.

Note: I'm using AAApackageDev to work on all of these in JSON.
currently, i have the below instruction:

```
...
    "endCaptures": {
        "0": {"name": "my.style"}
    },
    "begin": "(<style)(.*?>)(<!\\[CDATA\\[)",
    "end": "(]]></style>)",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "0": {"name": "my.style"}
    },
...
```

to find this code:

```
<style name="after"><![CDATA[
  <style type="text/css">
    div.awesome {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
]]></style>
```

and style as so:

```
...
{
    "scope": "my.style",
    "name": "my style",
    "settings": {
        "background": "#FF000"
    }
},
...
```

It should make the entire first and last line white with a red background, but it doesn't seem to be affected by it at all.

My question out of all of this: Is there any way to have the console show the syntax definition where my cursor is? If i could do this, debugging would be a breeze.